# Two classes with the same class name issue

Tags: swift, class

If having two classes with the same name, one created manually and one installed by pod,
the second one will have issues with accessing.

For example: we have used `SomeClass` class **whose name we dont want to change** since it is being used on too many spaces in the code, even the typealias would require many changes in code.
If we install pod `SomePod` which is having the same class name inside, `SomeClass`, and if we import the pod and try make an instance of it:

```
let instance = SomeClass()
```

then, the instance will recognize only class members of the first, manually created one, and if we try to use class members of `SomeClass` installed by pod, it will of course show errors like this:

`Value of type 'SomeClass' has no member 'someMember'.`

Additional issue is that pod's name is the same as it's main class name.
So my question is, is it possible to somehow accent to the instance that it should be the type of `SomeClass` from *pod*, without changing class names or creating typealiases?
For example:

```
let instance = SomePod.SomeClass()
```

Comment: Sometimes an unpopular and tedious procedure like changing the name could be  beneficial on the long run.

Comment: yes you can use ModuleName.TypeName instead of TypeName

Comment: Did you try that line of code before asking the question? Because that’s exactly how it works.

Comment: of course I did @EmilioPelaez but problem is that the ModuleName is the same as my class name.

Answer (score 3):

Qualifying a class name (or other type) by module (e.g. `Modulename.TypeName` as in Joakim's comment) is known as "namespacing" and it is meant for exactly this type of situation.

If you are able to rename your classes to avoid the conflict in the first place that would be ideal, since having the same name for two different classes will be confusing for people looking at your project (including you, a couple of years from now.) It also makes searching the code and documentation much harder.

Comment: thanks Duncan. But the problem is that the ModuleName is the same name as my custom class name. Pod is having the same name as its main class. So when typing `ModuleName.` Xcode observes it like a `CustomClass.` and shows only CustomClass's members.